# ngIf component shows briefly when it's not supposed to appear

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

This is Angular 4 application
i have a custom component that is supposed to show when the function returns true;

```
 <card *ngIf="isWrongStation()">
```

but this component shows when page is navigated, for a few milliseconds and then disappears.

any fix?

Comment: does it work in angular 4 ?

Comment: ng-cloak is for angularjs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can actually have a variable named isLoaded and make it true when your condition is met

```
<card *ngIf="isLoaded && isWrongStation()">
```

Comment: @Sanjeetharan Any other idea to deal with this problem.
Because I have to use one extra variable.

Comment: this would be the way, otherwise you can use canacativate but thats too costly

Comment: I am thinking calling function inside *ngIf means it will call mutiple times.
is this good for our project performance? 
I would like to know a general overview.

Comment: there is a logic that needs to return true or false. 
are you suggesting to set a boolean variable and use that variable instead?

Comment: @Sajeetharan i am trying out your solution.

Answer (score 0):

What does your `isWrongStation()` method look like? If it is test based on checking property's value, perhaps you could give it a default value, so that the statement defaults to a predictable value before the condition is evaluated.

e.g in your component class put `station = '';` for station to initially be set to an empty string value.